# A basic doubt on the proof of Cauchy schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Consider $x$ and $y$ be any two vectors. Let $k$ be any scalar.

Now the expression $\langle x-ky,x-ky\rangle$ is a non-negative quantity and it gets minimized when $k = \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}$ (it can be checked) i.e. at this $k$, $\langle x-ky,x-ky\rangle$ is zero which means $x-ky$ =null vector i.e. $x$ is a scalar multiple of $y$.

Take $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(3,2)$ in $R^2$ with $\langle x,y\rangle$ defined as $\langle x,y\rangle=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$. According to above at $k = \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle} = \frac{5}{13}, x=ky$. But this is not correct ? Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Where did you find the result that "at this $k$, $\langle x-ky, x-ky\rangle$ is zero"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the quantity $\langle x - ky, x - ky \rangle$ is non-negative does not mean that it is minimized when it is zero. If there is a $k$ such that $\langle x - ky, x - ky \rangle$ is zero, then yes, that $k$ minimizes it, but it is entirely possible that no $k$ exists such that it is zero.

For example, with what you have given, with $x = (1,1)$ and $y = (3,2)$, the minimum value of $\langle x - ky, x - ky \rangle$ is at $k = \frac{5}{13}$, at which point it will be $\langle (\frac{-2}{13}, \frac{3}{13}), (\frac{-2}{13}, \frac{3}{13}) \rangle = \frac{4}{13} + \frac{9}{13} = 1$. Despite this not being zero, it is the minimal value of $\langle (1 - 3k, 1 - 2k), (1 - 3k, 1 - 2k) \rangle$.

Comment: Yep. In $\mathbb R^1,\,f(x)=1+x^2$ is non-negative and minimized at $x=0$, but $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: understood my mistake.